# sinatra behind nginx resets the session

Tags: ruby, session, nginx, sinatra

[Update at the bottom] 
The problem is that after each reload of the page, regardless of what I put in the session, session gets 'reset'.

For example:

```
session[:test]="test"
puts session.inspect.to_s -> {"test"=>"test"}
(page reload)
puts session.inspect.to_s -> {"csrf"=>"b400efd6.....2362bd", "tracking"=>{"HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"12a007....b", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"...."}}
```

In my nginx configuration I have:

```
proxy_pass       http://localhost:9292;
```

In main.rb file I have:

```
configure do
(...)
set :sessions, key: '1234567',
    path: '/',
    expire_after: 86400,
    secret: '7654321'
(...)
end
```

[Update]
It turns out that the response does not contain - set-cookie with the session id. Currently I am using CF->NGINX->Thin/Sinatra. Everything works fine without nginx.

Comment: Try adding `proxy_cookie_domain localhost $host;`

Comment: tried, session is lost after page reload, redirect. Also tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844863/sinatra-clears-session-on-post

Comment: Does it work when you access the page directly on localhost:9292? Try isolate the problem either to nginx or to backend

Comment: it works on localhost, thought it was session stickiness but cookies are being set with the session

Comment: Session would always requires cookie?

Comment: check my updated response

Comment: ok I can see cookie with the session id is not being set when using nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157643/discussion-between-meso-2600-and-tarun-lalwani).